# Setting up multiple sites on single domain using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was looking for a solution to handle the multiple sites with multiple directories like a bloggers directory structure, for example:

```
asp.com/site1
asp.com/site2
asp.com/site3
```

How can I achieve this launching different sites to different directories/folders? I know I need to do something to config file but what???

Many thanks.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: It could be.  You can handle this in code. Best to let IIS or web server handle it usually.

Comment: you have to be more specific about your question. you can achieve this by 

* creating sub virualdirectories under a website on IIS.
* or one single web site and your code should handle routing values.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are virtual directories in IIS. Check out this MSDN article on how to set them up in IIS7:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173.aspx

Or go to this page to see how to set them up in other IIS versions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178477.aspx